# UWP. How To Implement drop shadow in code without using DropShadowPanel in

Tags: uwp, styling, dropshadow, dropshadoweffect

I'm not an expert in using Windows composition APIs. How to implement a DropShadow on either a control or a layout or any visual control in UWP without using a `DropShadowPanel` for some purposes. An attached example would be awesome. Also please make sure that the shadow effect is behind the control and doesn't overlay it

Comment: The DropShadowPanel is part of the open source Windows Community Toolkit. You can look at its source to see how it's implemented at https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/DropShadowPanel

Comment: I wrote a block of code depending on my understanding for the UWP DropShadowControl mechanism. And this is the block: [block](https://pastebin.com/QHHHXPn9)

Comment: But it didn't get applied

Comment: So is there is anything wrong in my code?

Answer (score 4):

In your code, you have created a `SpriteVisual` from the control's **Compositor** and configure the `SpriteVisual`'s shadow, but you don't set this `SpriteVisual` named `shadowVisual` as a child of the Visual tree so that you can not see the shadow to be applied. You can just put the following code in your code block's end.

```cs
...
ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(Control, shadowVisual);
```

Your code will look like this:

```cs
//Control is the control the shadow is applied to. e.g. Button, TextBlock etc.
Compositor compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(Control).Compositor;
var shadowVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
var dropShadow = compositor.CreateDropShadow();
shadowVisual.Shadow = dropShadow;

//UpdateShadowSize
Vector2 newSize = new Vector2(0, 0);
if (Control is FrameworkElement contentFE)
{
    newSize = new Vector2((float)contentFE.ActualWidth, (float)contentFE.ActualHeight);
    //newSize = new Vector2(200, 60);
}
shadowVisual.Size = newSize;

//Some hardcoded values for now
dropShadow.BlurRadius = 8;
dropShadow.Opacity = 0.3f;
dropShadow.Offset = new Vector3(new Vector2(2, 2), 0);
dropShadow.Color = Windows.UI.Colors.Black;

// Sets a Visual as child of the Control’s visual tree.
ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(Control, shadowVisual);
```

Note: I changed the `dropShadow.Opacity` to be `0.3f` to make the shadow more clear.

---Update---

Yeah, you can put a special element behind the MainContent then create the shadow from this element to make the shadow behind the Main content. `GetAlphaMask` method should work, here is an example, you can have a try.

xaml:

```xml
<Grid Loaded="Grid_Loaded">
    <!-- Canvas to create shadow-->
    <Canvas Name="canvas"/>
    <TextBlock x:Name="textBlcok" Text="this is text blcok for test shadow"/>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```cs
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //The canvas is the element to create shadow
    var compositor = ElementCompositionPreview.GetElementVisual(canvas).Compositor;
    var dropShadow = compositor.CreateDropShadow();
    dropShadow.Color = Colors.Green;
    dropShadow.BlurRadius = 8;
    dropShadow.Opacity = 20.0f;
    dropShadow.Offset = new Vector3(2.5F, 2.5F, 0);

    //The textBlock is the main content
    var mask = textBlcok.GetAlphaMask();
    dropShadow.Mask = mask;

    var spriteVisual = compositor.CreateSpriteVisual();
    spriteVisual.Size = new Vector2((float)canvas.ActualWidth, (float)canvas.ActualHeight);

    spriteVisual.Shadow = dropShadow;

    ElementCompositionPreview.SetElementChildVisual(canvas, spriteVisual);
}
```

Comment: I figured this out and the shadow is applied but i overlays the element. So what is did is a special element called ShadowElement behind the MainContent. Now the shadow i applied behind the main content and this is what we want.

Comment: Another issue i faced that the masks. UWP DropShadowPanel uses GetAlphaMask to get a specific kind of shadow for shapes and text. I use the same code but it doesn't work

Comment: I have added the **update** part with example code, you can have a try with the GetAlphaMask method. If you delete the code that set the mask, you will see the shadow will be applied on all the canvas range.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/windows-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq

This app contains many of controls to build a beautiful uwp applications, it has a shadow library you can see how to implement it in your project and give you a shadow to any control